# Get html from a webpage with cURL and strip html with preg-replace

Tags: php, html, regex, curl, preg-replace

I want to get the stats from The Pirate Bay, the stats can be found in the following div on TPB:

```
<div id="stats">5.695.184 registered users Last updated 14:46:05.<br />35.339.741 peers (25.796.820 seeders + 9.542.921 leechers) in 4.549.473 torrents.<br />    </div>
```

This is my code:

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://thepiratebay.se"); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIE,"language=nl_NL; c[thepiratebay.se][/][language]=nl_NL");
    $data=curl_exec($ch);
    $data = preg_replace('/(.*?)(<div id="stats">)(.*?)(<\/div>)(.*?)/','$2',$data);
    echo $data; 
    curl_close($ch); 
    exit;
?>
```

As you can see I use the following `preg-replace` pattern to strip the HTML:

```
$data = preg_replace('/(.*?)(<div id="stats">)(.*?)(<\/div>)(.*?)/','$2',$data);
```

But that is not working. I get the whole page of TPB and not only the stats. Somebody has an answer?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Forget doing screen scrapping with regex, use [domDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) instead, look how simple it is:

```
<?php 
function curl_get($url){
    $useragent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; Media Center PC 4.0)';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIE,"language=nl_NL; c[thepiratebay.se][/][language]=nl_NL");
    $data=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}

function get_pb_stats(){
    $html = curl_get("http://thepiratebay.se");
    // Create a new DOM Document
    $xml = new DOMDocument();

    // Load the html contents into the DOM
    @$xml->loadHTML($html);

    $return = trim($xml->getElementById('stats')->nodeValue);
    //regex to add the brake tag after 15:04:05. 
    $return = preg_replace('/\d{2}[:]\d{2}[:]\d{2}[.]/','${0}<br />',$return);
    return $return;
}

echo get_pb_stats();

/*
5.695.213 geregistreerde gebruikers Laatste update 15:04:05.<br />35.505.322 peers (25.948.185 seeders + 9.557.137 leechers) in 4.546.560 torrents.
*/
?>
```

Comment: Why don't you just `return strip_tags(trim($xml->getElementById('stats')->nodeValue));`?

Comment: Interesting, I just sort of assumed it would... will have a play around with it now.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. But can I get the `<br />` after 15:04:05. also? Because now it shows _Laatste update 15:04:05.35.505.322 peers_ and that's confusing. (I want to show _Laatste update 15:04:05.<br />35.505.322 peers_)

Comment: @TonHoekstra as its normal behaviour to strip out all html in nodeValue because `<` & `>` are not valid xml. So with some simple regex we can find the time string and append it with a `br` tag. Hope it helps. check the update

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use preg_match()?

```
preg_match('/<div id="stats">(.*)<br \/>/Usi', $data, $m);
$stats = $m[1];
```